# Attempt to invoke virtual method on null pointer reference

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to make a music application. So far I have been able to list the songs from a user's device and display them in a list. However, if a song is clicked to open the `PlayerActivity`, the activity crashes. Could someone assist me in playing the selected song from the song list? Improvements on the code would be highly appreciated.

The code below, `MediaGalleryActivity.java` gets the songs and passes them to specific intents:

```java
package com.newton.hooked;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.newton.hooked.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MediaGalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String SONGS_KEY = "SONGS";
    public static final String ARTISTS_KEY = "ARTISTS";
    public static final String ALBUMS_KEY = "ALBUMS";

    ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> artistList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> albumList = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] song = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_gallery);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        int defaultValue = 0;
        int page = getIntent().getIntExtra("Tab ID",defaultValue);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,song,null,null,null);
        ArrayList<AudioModel> audios = new ArrayList<>();

        if(audioCursor != null){
            if(audioCursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    int idColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                    int titleColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    int artistColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    int albumColumn = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);

                    String thisTitle = audioCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    String thisArtist = audioCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                    String thisAlbum = audioCursor.getString(albumColumn);

                    songList.add(thisTitle);
                    artistList.add(thisArtist);
                    albumList.add(thisAlbum);
                } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        audioCursor.close();

        if(!songList.isEmpty()){
            getIntent().putExtra(SONGS_KEY, songList);
        } else {
            getIntent().putExtra(SONGS_KEY,"No songs found");
        }

        if (!artistList.isEmpty()){
            getIntent().putExtra(ARTISTS_KEY,artistList);
        } else {
            getIntent().putExtra(ARTISTS_KEY,"No artists found");
        }

        if (!albumList.isEmpty()){
            getIntent().putExtra(ALBUMS_KEY,albumList);
        } else {
            getIntent().putExtra(ALBUMS_KEY,"No albums found");
        }

    }

}
```

The code below, `SongsTab.java`, gets songList extra and displays the items in a `ListView`

```java
package com.newton.hooked.ui.main;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.newton.hooked.MediaGalleryActivity;
import com.newton.hooked.PlayerActivity;
import com.newton.hooked.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SongsTab extends Fragment {

    public static final String SONG_POSITION = "POSITION";
    private ListView songList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_tab, container, false);

        songList = view.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        TextView message = view.findViewById(R.id.song_message);

        Intent intent = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getIntent();
        final ArrayList<String> songs = intent.getStringArrayListExtra(MediaGalleryActivity.SONGS_KEY);

        if (!songs.isEmpty()){
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()),R.layout.display_layout_2,R.id.txt_name,songs);
            songList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            songList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerActivity.class)
                            .putExtra("SONGLIST",songs)
                            .putExtra(SONG_POSITION,position)
                            .putExtra("SONG_ID",id));
                }
            });
        } else {
            songList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

The code below, `PlayerActivity.java`, is supposed to play a selected song:

```java
package com.newton.hooked;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.newton.hooked.ui.main.SongsTab;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_next, btn_previous, btn_pause;
    TextView songTextLabel;
    SeekBar songSeekBar;
    String sName;
    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    int position = 0;

    ArrayList<String> mySongs = new ArrayList<>();
    Thread updateSeekBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        btn_next = findViewById(R.id.next);
        btn_pause = findViewById(R.id.pause);
        btn_previous = findViewById(R.id.previous);
        songTextLabel = findViewById(R.id.song_label);
        songSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Now Playing...");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        updateSeekBar = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int totalDuration = myMediaPlayer.getDuration();
                int currentPosition = 0;

                while (currentPosition<totalDuration){
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                        currentPosition= myMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        songSeekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        if(myMediaPlayer!=null){
            myMediaPlayer.stop();
            myMediaPlayer.release();
        }

        Intent i = getIntent();

        mySongs = i.getStringArrayListExtra("SONGLIST");

        position = i.getIntExtra(SongsTab.SONG_POSITION, 0);

        String songName= i.getStringExtra("songName");

        long songID = i.getIntExtra("SONG_ID",0);
        songTextLabel.setText(songName);
        songTextLabel.setSelected(true);

        Uri u = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,songID);

        myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PlayerActivity.this,u);

        myMediaPlayer.start();
        songSeekBar.setMax(myMediaPlayer.getDuration());

        updateSeekBar.start();

        songSeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        songSeekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        songSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                myMediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });

        btn_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                songSeekBar.setMax(myMediaPlayer.getDuration());

                if(myMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    btn_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_play);
                    myMediaPlayer.pause();
                } else {
                    btn_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_pause);
                    myMediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myMediaPlayer.stop();
                myMediaPlayer.release();
                position = ((position +1)%mySongs.size());

                Uri u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());

                myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);

                sName = mySongs.get(position).toString();
                songTextLabel.setText(sName);

                myMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        btn_previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myMediaPlayer.stop();
                myMediaPlayer.release();

                position = ((position -1)%mySongs.size()-1);

                Uri u  = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());

                myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);

                sName = mySongs.get(position).toString();
                songTextLabel.setText(sName);

                myMediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I encounter the error below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.newton.hooked, PID: 2396
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.newton.hooked/com.newton.hooked.PlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.newton.hooked.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:90)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: A `MediaPlayer.create()` call has failed in `PlayerActivity.onCreate()` on code line 90 says the crash log. I suppose the reason must a problem with the `URI` that you pass as a parameter. You have the code line numbers in the IDE, so you'll know which one it is. Then you should focus on the `URI`. What is it? Why is it invalid?

Comment: The stacktrace tells you that there was a null pointer on line 90, where you call `myMediaPlayer.start()`. So this would mean that that myMediaPlayer was not initialized properly: `MediaPlayer.create(PlayerActivity.this,u)`. Check why the static method would return null. Maybe `u` is invalid.